# Having trouble in strpos() in php

Tags: php

[image: ScreenShot]Working fine for all comma separated values but not working for `Restauant` .
Please suggest what should i have to do this.

```
<?php 
        $service="Restaurant,24x7_room_service,Parking,currency_exchange,deposite_boxes,Laundry,pool,gym,AC,TV,Fridge,Intercom,Intercom,Extra Bed (if needed Chargeable)";

        //$dservices=str_ireplace(',',' ',$d['services']);
        $dservices="Restaurant,24x7_room_service,Parking,currency_exchange,deposite_boxes,Laundry,pool,gym,AC,TV";
        $loop=explode(",",$service);

        foreach($loop as $action)
        {
        ?>
<li style="width:50%;float:left;padding: 10px;"><?php  if(strpos($dservices,$action)=='') { echo '<i style="color:red;" class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>';}else{ ?><i style="color:#004386;" class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> <?php } ?><?= $action ?> </li>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: `strpos` returns a number, why are you comparing it with a string?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Niraj Gelani i have edited with screenshot please find.

Comment: Because your restuarant is at 0 position will is true for case , but false for your condition

Comment: Why don't you explode both strings, and use `in_array()`?

Comment: @Barmar That would definitely be a better fit.

Comment: Why should `Extra bed` have a checkmark? It's not in `$dservices`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your if condition with the following :

```
if(strpos($dservices, $action) === false)
```

Comment: Thank You Niraj Gelani `===` using this working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because your restaurant is at 0 position will is true for scenario,exist but  return value 0 is making your `if` condition false.

Changed this line of code

```
if(strpos($dservices,$action)=='')
```

to

```
if(strpos($dservices,$action)=== false)
```

This will check for position number and if does not exist return negative value.

Comment: What does "true for case" mean? That's not anything in English.

Comment: I still can't parse your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A better method would be to explode `$dservices` into another array, instead of using `strpos`.

```
$dservices_array = array_flip(explode(',', $dservices));
foreach ($loop as $action) {
    ?>
    <li style="width:50%;float:left;padding: 10px;">
    <?php  
    if(!isset($dservices_array[$action])) { 
        echo '<i style="color:red;" class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>';
    } else { 
        echo '<i style="color:#004386;" class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>';
    }
    echo $action;
    ?> </li>
<?php }?>
```

Using `strpos` can cause false matched. For instance, if `$action` is `TV` and `$dservices` contains `HDTV`.